# Sequelize afterCreate not firing

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js, sequelize-hooks

I am using Sequelize as an ORM with MySQL, Node and Express.

When inserting a new item to 'ExpertiseField' table, I want to update a field in a different table.

I'm having an issue with hooks in Sequelize, for some reason afterCreate appears to not do anything.

My 'ExpertiseField' model:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const ExpertiseField = sequelize.define('ExpertiseField', {
    name: DataTypes.STRING,
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    position: DataTypes.INTEGER
  }, {
    classMethods: {
      associate: function(models) {
        ExpertiseField.hasOne(models.LocalDataLastUpdatedAtItem);
      }
    },
    hooks: {
      afterCreate: function(expertiseField, options) {
        sequelize.models.LocalDataLastUpdatedAtItem.update({
          updatedAt: expertiseField.updatedAt
        },{
          where: {
            name: 'expertise_fields_last_updated_at'
          }
        });
      }
    }
  });
  ExpertiseField.associate = function(models) {
    // associations can be defined here
  };
  return ExpertiseField;
};
```

the hook I'm creating isn't doing anything, any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

Answering my question so maybe it helps someone from making my mistake in the future.

Apparently Sequelize hooks works inside the code only.
When editing my table from a 3rd party SQL-Viewer program nothing happened and I thought something was wrong.. but when running my code everything worked fine.